# Remove upper case in column names in a PostGIS spatial table to permit use in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql

As of ArcMap for Desktop 10.4 it is increasingly easy to attach a PostgreSQL instance running PostGIS to ArcMap.

I also know it is a best practice in PostgreSQL to not name tables or columns using mixed case.  While PostgreSQL can handle mixed case names by quoting them (`""`), this can cause issues with other software, and can be onerous when generating queries.

ArcMap is also fussy in this regard.  For example, it will fail when asked to render a table or a materialized view when the name is not entirely lower case.  It will also fail when any column in that table has a mixed case name.

I am wondering if it is possible to create a dynamic way to automatically sanitize table information in a `SELECT` query in order to create a materialized view that can be added easily in ArcMap.

For example:

`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW myspatialtable_arcmap AS (
SELECT arcmap_sanitize_select('SELECT * FROM "mySpatialTable"')`

**If so, what approach could be used in this function? Or is there a better a way to do this?**

I should mention that it does need to be dynamic as the column names do change frequently, and because there are other client dependencies on the base tables it is not possible to rename the columns to remove upper case.

Comment: I think you're in a world of pain as long as the column names keep on changing. Any way of changing the design to stop this? AFAIK views need to know the columns in advance, so if they change you have to drop and rebuild the view. Only thing I can think of is a function that drops and recreates a table with sanitized column names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  This was a pain, but I did manage to solve this myself.  I am posting an answer for others who may face this problem.

In summary, I made a function that creates a materialized view with forced lower case column names.  I also added an option to include an incrementing integer `gid` that ArcMap requires, and in some PostGIS spatial tables may be missing.  Note there is no error checking here, so a table with columns `"AAA"` and `"aaa"` which would work fine if these identifiers were quoted will now fail.  Also, ArcMap requires that all identifiers coming from PostgreSQL must be 31 characters or less.  A sanitize function should ideally be able to handle this as well.

The following function:

1. Extracts the table definition SQL for the table of interest and lower cases the column names.  (I did this by modifying the function given by Toader at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593803/how-to-generate-the-create-table-sql-statement-for-an-existing-table-in-postgr
2. Creates a new materialized view with the same table name in lower case, with a suffix appended (`'_arcmap'`) by default, which can be set using the `view_suffix` parameter.  It drops this materialized view first if it exists.
3. Optionally creates a new index column for ArcMap called gid (`create_gid` option).  This is helpful if the spatial table does not already have a numerical integer index.

The function below can be called as follows:

`SELECT create_sanitized_view_arcmap('mySpatialTable', true, 'arcmap')`

and will create a new materialized view called `myspatialtable_arcmap` with an integer row index called `gid`.  For error checking purposes it will return the SQL used to created the materialized view.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_sanitized_view_arcmap
  (p_table_name
    VARCHAR,
   create_gid
    BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
   view_suffix
    VARCHAR DEFAULT 'arcmap')
  RETURNS TEXT
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  v_table_ddl   TEXT;
  column_record RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR column_record IN
  SELECT
    b.nspname                                       AS schema_name,
    b.relname                                       AS table_name,
    a.attname                                       AS column_name,
    pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS column_type,
    CASE WHEN
      (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) FOR 128)
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
       WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef) IS
      NOT NULL
      THEN
        'DEFAULT ' ||
        (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) FOR 128)
         FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
         WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef)
    ELSE
      ''
    END                                             AS column_default_value,
    CASE WHEN a.attnotnull = TRUE
      THEN
        'NOT NULL'
    ELSE
      'NULL'
    END                                             AS column_not_null,
    a.attnum                                        AS attnum,
    e.max_attnum                                    AS max_attnum
  FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
       c.oid,
       n.nspname,
       c.relname
     FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
       LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
     WHERE c.relname ~ ('^(' || p_table_name || ')$')
           AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
     ORDER BY 2, 3) b
      ON a.attrelid = b.oid
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
       a.attrelid,
       max(a.attnum) AS max_attnum
     FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
     WHERE a.attnum > 0
           AND NOT a.attisdropped
     GROUP BY a.attrelid) e
      ON a.attrelid = e.attrelid
  WHERE a.attnum > 0
        AND NOT a.attisdropped
  ORDER BY a.attnum
  LOOP
    IF column_record.attnum = 1
    THEN
      v_table_ddl:='CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || LOWER(column_record
                                                        .table_name)
                   || '_' || view_suffix || ' AS (SELECT ';
      IF create_gid = TRUE
      THEN
        v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl || chr(10) || '(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ())
              ::integer
               AS gid,';
      END IF;
    ELSE
      v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl || ',';
    END IF;

    IF column_record.attnum <= column_record.max_attnum
    THEN
      v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl || chr(10) ||
                   '    "' || column_record.column_name || '" AS ' ||
                   LOWER(column_record.column_name);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl || ' FROM "' || column_record.schema_name ||
               '"."' || column_record.table_name || '");';
  EXECUTE format('DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS %s',
                 LOWER(column_record.table_name) || '_' || view_suffix);
  EXECUTE format('%s', v_table_ddl);
  RETURN v_table_ddl;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```